# SVM - support vectors on the wrong side of the margin for polynomial kernel

Tags: svm, kernel-trick

In soft-margin SVM, the constraint in soft-margin (compared to hard-margin) is $0≤α_i≤C$ for some positive constant C. We say that:

If $α_i=C$, then the corresponding $x_i$ is on the wrong side of the margin

So it's the same as: $-1<w^T x_i + b<1$

My question is, is the above equation also true for polynomial kernel?

For $x_i$ to be on the wrong side of the margin would it mean to be  $-1<w^T x_i + b<1$?

Comment: $-1 < w^T x_i + b < 1$ is when $x_i$ is **within** the margin. $x_i$ is on the wrong side if $y_i(w^T x_i + b) < 1$.

Comment: Does it apply for polynomial kernel also?

Comment: I don't see any reason why it should not be true for a kernel SVM with polynomial kernel. Can you please say what makes think it might not be the case there? Please note that due to Mercer's theorem any Mercer kernel can be thought of as a dot product (linear) kernel in a high (or possibly infinite) dimensional space.

Comment: Now I understand why I am wrong, when we convert to the dual form: $w^T\Phi (x) +b=\sum_{\alpha_i\neq 0} y_i \alpha_i K(x_i,x)+b$. So the kernel doesn't matter to the primal equation $w^T\Phi (x) +b$.

Comment: Yes, and this is only true when you can write $K(x_i, x)$ as $\phi(x_i)^T \phi(x)$ for some feature map $\phi(cdot)$.

Comment: Just to make sure, so in order to test whether $x_j$ lies on the wrong side of the margin, for a non-linear kernel, I should do this: $y_j(\sum_{x_i \in SV} y_i \alpha_i K(x_i,x_j)+b)<1$?

Comment: yes, that should do!